# AciTree how to cache or clone

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, acitree

In project we use AciTree plugin from http://acoderinsights.ro/, together with checkbox extension, great plugin. 
We encountered a problem, when we draw tree with 3000+ nodes. It takes 30 seconds to load all nodes into DOM. Another catch is, this tree must be showed dynamicali on several places on page with same structure, but with diferent checked nodes. 
Maybe unique solution is caching or cloning. Create tree in background an then clone this tree when it's needed, reducing time to creating new aciTree object.
I tried this code flow,but with no luck.
On page load generate cache and keep it in memory.
Code may contain errors, this is showed only for logic flow.

```
var mytree = {
    tree: {},
    settings: {checkbox:true}
    cache: function(radio){
        var html = '<div id="selectbox_categories" class="aciTree"></div>';

        mytree.tree = jQuery(html).aciTree(mytree.settings);
        var api = mytree.tree.aciTree('api');
        api.loadFrom(null, {'itemData': treeData, 'unanimated': true, 
        'success': function (){
            console.log('Caching Success!');
            /* Do some logic */
        }
    });
 }
```

And then call function to clone aciTree object like this.

```
function cloneTree( elem ) {

   // elem is real empty html dom element in page
   var box = jQuery(elem);

   if( box.length > 0 ){

    // Tried this but when using api on this, nothing happens...
    var cloned = mytree.tree.clone(true, true);
    box.replaceWith( cloned );

    // Tried this also...
    //box = jQuery.extend(true, {}, mytree.tree.clone(true, true));

    var api = box.aciTree(mytree.settings);

    // Tried this also...
    //box.aciTree('init', js_category.settings);

    var jsa = box.aciTree('api');

    // When using api, for example check nodes nothing happens...
    jsa.search(null, {
        'search': id, 
        'success': function (i) {
             console.log('found...');
             jsa.check(jQuery(i));
        }, 
        'fail':function(){
             console.log('failed...');
        }
    });
}
```

My javascript knowledge is poor and i wonder if there is a possibility for cloning entire aciTree object with events, etc..., for instant tree insertion into requested place in page dom.

Thanx for all advices...